# String.Format has a bug when I try to parse html tags

Tags: c#, html, string.format

Well, I'm doing an geshi syntax reader for Unity, and well, I'm having some trouble setting new values from some html tags.

There is my code: http://rextester.com/BZH23246

I will try to explain as clear as possible.

Simply, I get CSS styles from a string and I store them on a Dictionary.

Then, I use another method to get all innerHTML from the div that contains all the code (Yes, I'm using htmlagilitypack, but in Rextester as it's logic I can't use it, so, I write the full string manually).

When I got all the HTML, I get tag by tag, and I replace it, using ContentFormatter method. Inside it, I get the previous values gotten from the CSS parse method and the Dictionary.

The first method (ContentMultiFormatted) has the CSS value splitted into CSS Selectors and their values. Example:

**.somelement{color:white;font-size:12;}**

This is transformed into:

Key: **somelement**

Value: **color:white;font-size:12;**

---

When ContentFormatter is called, this value is obtained depending on the class we selected, and this splitted newly into two values, this is time getting all styles from this element.

---

Key: **color**

Value: **white**

Key: **font-size**

Value: **12**

---

When this happens I classify the values. Returning what its supossed to be replaced.

So, if I have this two values, I have to convert a `<span>` tag into `<color=white><size=12>` and `</span>` tag into `</size></color>`.

For some reason, when an bold tag is opened, later it's not closed. And I don't know what I have to do.

I tried like 10 ways to solve it, without any luck. You can imagine, I'm almost going crazy.

I think, it has more than one bug, but I cannot check it because, the actual problem doesn't me advance.

Comment: This question could do with summarising, TL;DR

Comment: What? I didn't understand what you mean @Liam, sorry...

Comment: It's very long. you should try and sum your problem up in a shorter explanation. TL;DR = Too Long; Didn't Read. I don't think I'm the only one given the small number of views and lack or comments/answers

Comment: Oh okey, thanks for your tip, I will think what can I do... :-/